# Problems using EF4.1 Code First with MVC3 and MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am following this guide: http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

So that is MVC3 with EF Code First and I am trying to use MySQL instead of SQLSERVER.

So far I have downloaded the MySqlConnector/Net (and also Devart dotConnect).
In my web.config I have added the following under

```
<add name="ProjectContext"
     connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=project; Uid=root; Pwd=pass;"
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Next, I found out that the following also has to be added to the web.config. I don't know why though.

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <clear/>
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

I have a simple POCO model for a post called Post.
I am under the impression that when this compiles, and the lazy loading kicks in, the entity framework should create a table for me that's called 'post' (or 'posts').

However, when this runs, I get the following error: "Table 'project.posts' doesn't exist" indicating that the EF does NOT create this for me.

When I use the dotConnect instead, I get the another error: "Unknown database 'dbo'".

**Does anyone have some insight as to what's going on?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql Connector/NET did not support Entity Framework Code First until version 6.6.

For a tutorial on MVC with Connector/NET see https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/building_an_mvc_3_application

Answer (score 1):

We have already replied to you at our forum [here](http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=20850).
Feel free to contact us if you encounter any other problems with our components.

Comment: It appears that you also copied the question into your forums. But thanks. Now it works with dotConnect. Although at $199.5 for a license, it's probably cheaper to go for MSSQL hosting.

Comment: I thought it was your post. Sorry for that, I should have posted the complete answer here.