# Schema not supported error in asp.net mvc web api

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am working on asp.net mvc 4 web api. I am using code first with existing database model. I have a single table in my database so i have the entity class like,

```
public class Tab1
{
[Key]
public int Field1{get; set;}
public string Field2{get; set;}
}
```

I have DBContext file like,

```
public class MyDBContext:DbContext
{
public DbSet<Tab1> Table{ get; set; }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
           modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().ToTable("bars");
        }
}
```

and my Get Action is like

```
 public List<Bar> GetTables()
            {
               MyDBContext context=new MyDBContext();
                return context.Table.ToList();
            }
```

But I am getting an error **Schema specified is not valid error 0064: Facet 'MaxLength' must not be specified for type 'mediumtext'.**. so please guide if i did any mistake in the process.

Here i have one more class like

```
public class Tab2:Tab1
{
public string Filed3{get; set;}
}
```

I dont want to create table in database with tab2 since i used tab2 class for returning custom records. I got the above error due to Tab2 inheriting from tab1 when i remove class tab2 it works as usual. so please guide me.

Comment: If you do use mysql it seems that is a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700497/class-inheritance-with-net-ef4-1-mysql

Answer (score 0):

If you problem is only caused when introducing the "Tab2" class in the model and you don't really want "Tab2" to be stored in the database why don't you just annotate the "Tab2" class with the the [NotMapped] attribute or use the fluent configuration ModelBuilder.Ignore.