# How to create custom class in ef codefirst model in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, asp.net-web-api

I am working on asp.net web api. I am using EF 4.1 code first model with existing database. I have a class like,

```
public class Tab1
{
public int ID{get; set;}
public string FirstName{get; set;}
public string LastName{get; set;}
}
```

and i have created dbcontext like,

```
public class EFBarContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Tab1> User{ get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tab1>().ToTable("User");
        }
    }
```

At first i need to get all records from table "User" and i need to calculate fullname based on firstname and lastname and i need to return the data json format like,

```
{"ID":212,"firstname":"kio","lastname":"nmk","fullname":"kionmk"}
```

for that i have created a custom class like,

```
public class Tab2:Tab1
{
public fullname{get; set;}
}
```

and i return the list with `List<Tab2>` But i am getting an error like  **`Schema specified is not valid error 0064: Facet 'MaxLength' must not be specified for type 'mediumtext'.`** 
I have followed the following post, [Class Inheritance with .NET EF4.1 + MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700497/class-inheritance-with-net-ef4-1-mysql) but i cant figure it out in my situation. so please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Your fullname property is derived from firstname and lastname, so I would not create a separate table in the db to store this (which is what you are doing with your `Tab2:Tab1` class).

Instead, you can derive this field in your webapi controller:

```
using (var context = new EFBarContext())
{
    var jsonObject = context.User.Select(x => new {
        ID = x.ID,
        firstname = x.FirstName,
        lastname = x.LastName,
        fullname = string.Format("{0}{1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName),
    });
}
```

No need for the separate inherited entity class in the db.